# Can I get back my WordPress local website if I have its database?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, localhost

My laptop recently broke and it had to be formatted for it to work again. I was working on a WordPress website that was almost done so it got all erased.

I have the MySQL database of the website. Can this help me to get back my website?

Comment: If you have a database dump (`.sql`, `.sql.gzip`) then yes you can import it into MySQL. Check on your preferred search engine "how to import an .sql file in MySQL".

Comment: Custom themes are stored as files: images, asset files like CSS, HTML files, and PHP files. If you don't have a backup of those then they are lost (unless you want to try disk recovery software). However yes, much of the written content (posts) will be in the database backup.

Comment: @cabrerahector I imported the Wordpress database to MySQL but I cannot connect it to a new Wordpress file. Any idea how?

Comment: @halfer To be honest, I am a noob, so I only got the database of the website but I do not know what it has in it.
I want to know please if I can recover the website by connecting the database somehow to a new Wordpress document in my Xampp server.
Is that possible?

Comment: It is possible, but if you are unsure how to do this, it is not going to be easy for someone to walk you through that here. Since you have a database server running with your old database, I would suggest using a database client system to read the tables, and export data in CSV or via your clipboard. Look at MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin for this.

Comment: Semi-manual recreation of your site is only feasible if you have a small number of posts to recreate. But if you have a large number, viewing them in a db client is still not a bad idea, so you can check what data you have rescued.